# Steps of Job Execution with Yarn

Tags: hadoop2

I'm new to Hadoop.

What are exactly MR application Master and container?
What are the steps of the job execution with Yarn.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationMaster is a instance of a framework-specific library and is responsible for negotiating resources from the ResourceManager and working with the NodeManager on all the hosts to execute and monitor the containers and their resource consumption.

container : Application execution happens inside containers.